# what does "visible deprecation" warning mean?

Tags: python, valueerror, mmf

I used next python code to extract the Eigen matrix (EI) of two mmf matrices texts.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import re
import scipy.linalg as la
data=loadtxt('matKSMMF.txt',skiprows=8)
s = len (data)
print(s)
n=6567
kmat = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
for x in range (s):
    m=data[x:x+1,:]
    kmat[int (m[0,0])-1][int (m[0,1])-1]=m[0,2]
K=np.array(kmat)
print (K)
data=loadtxt('matMSMMF.txt',skiprows=8)
s = len (data)
print(s)
n=6567
Mmat = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
for x in range (s):
    m=data[x:x+1,:]
    Mmat[int (m[0,0])-1][int (m[0,1])-1]=m[0,2]
M=np.array(Mmat)
print (M)
inv_M = np.linalg.inv(M)
print(inv_M)
L= la.eig(inv_M @ K)
print ('Eigen vector matrices is', L)
EI=np.array(L)
print (EI)
```

Unfortunately, I received the next warnings upon running:

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  EI=np.array(L)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mmf.py", line 30, in <module>
    EI=np.array(L)
-ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (6567,6567) into shape (6567,)
```

What is the meaning of such a warning/error? and how can I fix them?

Comment: It literally tells you what you can do to fix the warning.

Comment: Since Python code is not compiled, it cannot tell at compilation if you're using a deprecated feature so the way to do it is to tell you via a warning that will be visible to the dev when it executes the code, hence the name "Visible Deprecation Warning". If you see this warning, change your code accordingly to the recommendation to stay up-to-date with the current API. If not, your code might not work when you update the library in the future.

Comment: ```L= la.eig(inv_M @ K)```
```print ('Eigen vector matrices is', L)```
```EI=np.array(L)```
Are you sure this is what you intended to do? `eig` returns a list that includes a vector of eigenvalues and a matrix of eigenvectors

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé Python *is* (at least, with the most-used implementation CPython) compiled; the problem is that the *language* does not provide any way to mark something as deprecated. There are on-going discussions to add type-hint-like deprecation markers, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
L= la.eig(inv_M @ K)
print ('Eigen vector matrices is', L)
EI=np.array(L)
print (EI)
```

If you want to get the array of eigenvectors you can just do this:

```py
EI=L[1]
```

`scipy.linalg.eig` returns a list that contains a vector of eigenvalues and an array of eigenvectors

Comment: Is L [1] returns only 1st eigen vector ? and what have I to do to get all of eigen vectors as columns in on array ?

Comment: `L` is a list that contains a vector of eigenvalues and a matrix of eigenvectors, so `L[0]` is the vector of eigenvalues and `L[1]` is the matrix of eigenvectors